# MYSQL - Syntax error in Delete query which has in clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a sample schema and its SQL Fiddle is as follows:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6816b/2

This fiddle just queries the sample database based on condition in where clause as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p_outer
WHERE age IN
(SELECT age AS age1
FROM person p_inner
WHERE first_name='Anne');
```

```
The output of the same is:

    
     ID    FIRST_NAME AGE    GENDER
      1    Bob        25       MM
      8    Anne       25       FF
```

I have a delete query which has a inner query as below:

```
DELETE
FROM person p_outer
WHERE age IN
(SELECT age
FROM person p_inner
WHERE first_name='Anne');
```

SQL Fiddle for the above query is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6816b/3

This query works without issue in Oracle DB, when I run the same in MYSQL DB I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
    'p_outer
   WHERE age IN
     (SELECT age
     FROM person p_inner
     WHERE first_n' at line 2:
```

Also the MYSQL version is 5.6.13.

Please let know if some issue in the above syntax.

Comment: There's no reason to assign a table a pseudonym in this query. Just delete the p_outer and p_inner parts from the delete query and it should be fine.

Comment: Does your particular version and installation of MySQL permit subqueries? Not all do. Check with your host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
DELETE a.*
FROM person a
join person b on a.age = b.age and b.first_name = 'Anne';
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ac3c/1)

Comment: Plus cause I prefer to avoid IN selects when the same thing can be achieved using a basic join.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from person where age in (
Select age from (
                Select age from person where first_name='Anne'
         )  as s 
);
```

This is what you need..

Comment: You should explain why this works when the original query doesn't.

Comment: of course. you couldn't use same table as sub-query in delete and update query. So i have select the list of age from given first_name and this list considered as a temporary table as s . then the values of s(temporary table) given in to delete query. This is most simple way to do this..

Comment: . . The explanation isn't for my benefit.  It is for the OP's (I know how MySQL works).  My comment was friendly advice on answering questions.